# How to automatically change shipping price to free shipping if product price is higher than "500"?

Tags: shipping, onepage-checkout, shopping-cart-price-rules

I currently have a one-step-checkout page.

**In the following example i'd like the shipping price to automatically be "0" (free shipping) or the string "Free" if the price is higher than xxx.**

I've looked around for options to do this in the Magento backend, but cant seem to find anything to do this. I also looked in the Magento extensions library for something there, but no luck.

Guess hardcoding something on frontend-only doesn't quite do it, since this should also reflect/show in emails and invoices.

Any ideas on anything smart out there that could solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you add a shopping cart price rule.  Here is the how to.
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/3_-_store_setup_and_management/shopping-cart-price-rule-recipes

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: well the answer is google and read the how to's right?  It's more of a failure to do the basic things needed to answer the question your self IMNHO since I'd just be coping the write up from Magento themselves

Comment: This is a basic Stackexchange moderation response. Don't take it personally. But the answer is yes, it's desirable to copy the content from the source into the answer; make sure to attribute the source.

Comment: Accepting this one, since I ended up following the instructions posted in the url in the section of "Free shipping on orders over $XX" - this made it all work for me. I agree it would make sence to post the description or similar from there on this page, but not sure what the right thing to do here is

Comment: I've found that the right way on this is a moving target, I have been down voted for coping the instructions on SO but well important part is that you find your solution. Cheers

Answer (score 4):

Essentially all you have to do is enable the free method and it's free price breakpoint in your shipping method settings. Navigate to `System > Config > Shipping Methods` and select your carrier (UPS in this instance).

Set the `Free Method`, the `Free Shipping w/ Minimum Amount` and the `Minimum Order Amount` fields.

[image]

Comment: Hi Phil - thanks for the suggestion. What you suggest seems to somewhat solve my problem, but make another appear. Enabling this will make an additional section appear on the checkoutpage that enables the user to chose whether to deliver with free shipping. Im basically looking not to have this section but just have the shipping price automatically update. For this I found you need to create a price rule according to the url posted: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/3_-_store_setup_and_management/shopping-cart-price-rule-recipes

Answer (score 3):

Try Table rate method in magento for setting free shipping like this. You can also set free shipping to specific state,city using Table rate.
Rule for free shipping 500 and above:

[image]

To set up Table Rates go to System -> Configuration and Select Shipping Methods from the Left Navigation. Select Your desired website " Current Configuration Scope". I have selected "Main Website". Make settings like below screenshot:
Upload the CSV file and save config to apply the rule to your store.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Ill surely try this out at some point

Answer (score 1):

Use Table rates

Checkout this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19930298/magento-shipping-method/19930387

I hope this solves your problem.